How to get Université de Picardie Jules Verne, Chemin du Thil, Amiens from Central Bus Station at CDG Airport?
I would like to take a train (TGV, RER, or TER) from CDG airport (central bus station) to Amiens (Université de Picardie Jules Verne, Chemin du Thil).
I was looking at sncf-connect and found the following stations near Central Bus Station at CDG airport:

I am not sure which one is the nearest to the Central Bus Station at CDG airport. I see the last station in the below list (i.e., Paris Roissy Charles De Gaulle Airport TGV station) is about 20 km away from the Central Bus Station (CDG airport) with a 20 Euro ticket for Amiens. But I am not sure how to get from Central Bus Station (CDG) to that TGV station.
Is any other place in the below list that's closer to the Central Bus Station (CDG airport)?
I am interested to board from the Central Bus station (CDG airport) because a Flixbus will drop me there at the end of my previous trip.
Any guidance is appreciated.

"Central Bus Station" doesn't seem to be an official name but it looks like the FlixBus stop is here, next to the Hilton.
If you can walk 150 meters to the Roissypole / Terminal 3 station of the free CDGVAL shuttle, you can take the CDGVAL directly to the TGV station in Terminal 2.  Then you can get a train from there to Amiens as you have already found.
The total distance from the bus stop to the TGV station is about 1.1 km.  I am not sure where you got the idea that it was 20 km.  The "25 km from Paris" in your screenshot just indicates that the station is 25 km from the city center of Paris, which is true, but irrelevant because you don't need to go into the center at all.

Thank you. Yes I am wrong about 20 km distance as you mentioned. So you are saying that I can pick CDGVAL shuttle bus from terminal 3 towards terminal 2 where the TGV station is located. Is it?

@MAS: Correct.  Though CDGVAL is not a bus, more like a train (or a "people mover").

Nate's answer is spot on about the TGV station at Paris CDG
However, no services actually run to Amiens city central railway station from CDG train station
You can either get the RER (directly from Terminal 3 station) to Gare Du Nord and then hop on a TER train to Amiens central, taking 2h16min. Costing €11.80 for the RER trip to Gare Du Nord and €23.80 for the TER to Amiens.
You can also, from CDG TGV station take a TGV to Haute-Picardie TGV station (32min) and then take a 45min coach service to Amiens central. Pricing of the TGV is variable but the coach to Amiens is €10.
You can book all of that through SNCF Connect or Trainline

Good point. OP might also want to check if they can book their FlixBus to a different Paris stop than CDG, from which they may be able to get to Gare du Nord more cheaply.

There are also Flixbus routes directly from the CDG bus station to the University in Amiens (“Campus” stop).

@NateEldredge, my flixbus can drop me at Paris bercy-seine instead of CDG airport. Is it nearby to Gare du Nord? I think it is nearest to Gare du Lyon?

@jcaron, yes flixbus run from CDG to Amiens but it's timing is not suitable for me because they will reach at night at amiens while I want to settle at daytime

Is the University Picardie Jules Verne nearest to Amiens central station? Second, you said 45 minutes coach service? I am not aware of what a coach service is. Can you please explain it?

@MAS Coach = long-distance bus service. To go from the station to the University, you need to take a 25min local bus ride

@MAS: Paris Bercy-Seine is not close to Gare du Nord (you can help yourself out here by looking at a map before asking) but you can take Paris Metro or RER from there to Gare du Nord for €2.15.
